# Can a patch GPS-antenna be mounted in an inclined position?

Tags: antenna, gps

I have just bought Globsat BU353S4 GPS-receiver. Now I have a doubt: it is mandatory to mount it in an horizontal position (i.e. facing the sky) or it can be also tilted of some angle with no perceptible loss in precision?

I'm talking about an ideal situation: two antennas with zero obstacles around them. One is mounted horizontally, while the other has some angle with respect to the terrain.

As I know, usually this patch antennas have a ground plane. Maybe that metallic plane can obstruct the view of one or more satellites... but I'm not sure, this is just a personal speculation.

P.S.
I'm struggling to mount it on a motorcycle, so there is not a big choice of places where the antenna can be mounted.

[image]

Comment: please perform an experiment and ask a question afterward, if you still have a question

Comment: Google for a 3D image of a "patch antenna radiation pattern" and judge for yourself.

Comment: You asked about "precision". That's not affected. The ability to see satellites and get a fix, is what's affected.

Comment: @gbarry Precision can be affected. If the receiver can only see a subset of the satellites with less-than-ideal geometry, Dilution Of Precision will be increased. If it sees them through a lower-gain portion of the antenna beam pattern and picks up more terrestrial thermal noise and interference through the higher-gain portion of the pattern, then each pseudorange measurement will be noisier and this will also degrade the solution quality.

Comment: @jsotola - I have to build a special alu-bracket with a milling-machine in order to mount the receiver in the intended position on my motorbike. It would be nice to have some (even rough) indication before wasting money and time.

Comment: @gimpo, maybe i misunderstood ... i understood that you already own a GPS receiver and an antenna .... it does not take much work to perform a test by holding the antenna in varying positions and observing the result

Comment: @jsotola, my fault. I have ordered the GPS-antenna and waiting for the delivery. I had several (cheap) gps-antennas in the past for my auto. All of them was working well when mounted on the roof of my auto.
On a motorcycle everything is more complicated... I saw some product manuals stating that also the body of the driver is going to obstruct the satellite view.
My idea was to attach the antenna on the internal side of my tall windscreen, so it will be in the highest position possible. But it will be too tilted, so I have to discharge this idea and build a proper bracket somehow.

Comment: @jsotola
about testing: with my Samsung tablet (one with the best GPS receivers available for this device class) I get random result. The good signal that I get when the bike is not moving (fix point is get in a matter of seconds) is not replied when I start driving.
Very often it loose the signal even in open spaces with a clear and optimal view of the sky. I cannot find an explanation for that. So I think that a "real" test can be done only while driving. 
The tablet is strongly tilted with respect of the ground (maybe 70 degree or more), and it is facing the driver (me).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes.

If you look at the radiation pattern you can observe that the antenna "sees" the sky all around with the same "sensitivity" (ie. is omnidirectional). Horizontal mounting is ideal, because the satellites can be anywhere in the sky.

When such an antenna would be mounted at 90 degrees (extreme tilt), then half of the sky would be shielded by the ground plane, so the receiver could get signal from half of the satellites. Most of the time it should be enough to sustain a fix, so I think a small tilt can be accepted.

[image]

Picture from: https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Installed-Radiation-Pattern-of-Patch-Antennas%3A-on-a-Gao-Wang/2ffd12945b0588bf76fcd0408cc0d9c1c82737d8

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. You've confirmed me my suspects.